# Argument of \begin has an extra } when trying to use cases

Tags: pdftex, cases

I've just moved to compiling LaTeX on my desktop instead of using Overleaf and all's going fine, but I can't seem to be able to use the `cases` environment. Here's my code (some lines removed for brevity):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

%wieksze marginesy
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

%(...............)

Oczywiście $(1, \ldots, 1) \in W^\perp$. Gdy $\mathrm{char}k\mid n$, to również $(1, \ldots, 1) \in W$, a zatem $W \cup W^\perp \neq \{0\}$ i $W, W^\perp$ są podprzestrzeniami zdegenerowanymi. Niech $\mathrm{char}k \nmid n$. Załóżmy, że $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \notin \mathrm{lin}\{(1, \ldots, 1)\}, (a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in W^\perp$. Istnieją $i, j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ takie, że $a_i \neq 0$, $a_j \neq a_i$. Załóżmy dla wygody, że $i = 1$, $j = 2$. Rozważmy układ równań

$$
\begin{cases}
    x_1 + \ldots + x_n & = 0 \\
    a_1x_1 + \ldots + a_nx_n & = 0
\end{cases}
\xrightarrow
\begin{cases}
    x_1 + \ldots + x_n & = 0 \\
    (\frac{a_2}{a_1} - 1)x_2 + \ldots + (\frac{a_n}{a_1} - 1)x_n & = \frac{1}{a_1}
\end{cases}
$$

\end{document}
```

Compiling with `pdflatex` gives

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 26--28

! Argument of \begin  has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.37 \begin
           {cases}
? 
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \begin  was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.37 \begin
           {cases}
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.37 \begin
           {cases}
? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.37 \begin
           {cases}
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.37 \begin
           {cases}
? 
! Limit controls must follow a math operator.
\ext@arrow ...x to\wd \tw@ {\unhbox \z@ }}\limits 
                                                  \@ifnotempty {#7}{^{\if 0#...
l.37 \begin
           {cases}
? 
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.37 \begin
           {cases}
? 
)
! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 37.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> birula.tex
```

I've tried a couple of things but to me, my use of `cases` just seems completely inoffensive. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\xrightarrow` takes an argument (try `\xrightarrow{asdf}` to see). Use `\xrightarrow{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing `\xrightarrow` which has a mandatory argument (the text to be placed above the extensible arrow).

As a consequence of the parsing rules of TeX, it scans the next token as the mandatory argument, which happens to be `\begin`. Chaos ensues.

What you need is `\rightarrow`.